# Implement Ejabberd MUC Sub for iOS

Tags: ios, ejabberd, multiuserchat

We are implementing a chatting system that allow users to receive messages/notification when they are not connected to a MUC group, and I know that Ejabberd supported it from 16.08, via this document:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/#list-of-subscriptions
However I can't find any example for iOS implementation
I wonder if any one has implemented this feature on iOS, or any guidelines to implement this

Comment: any update for this? im looking for way to implement this too, any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Include XMPPMUCSub.h and .m file into your project.

Now after connecting xmppstream activate XMPPMUCSub service for activation use below code.

```
xmppMucSub = [[XMPPMUCSub alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppMucSub activate:xmppStream];
[xmppMucSub addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Now you have to implement delegate methods of XMPPMUCSub for method check class and implement it.

Now when every you create new xmpproom you need to call below method.

```
[xmppMucSub supportedBy:<Your xmpproom>];
```

if service support then below delegate method call and you need to subscribe it.

```
- (void)xmppMUCSub:(nonnull XMPPMUCSub *)sender serviceSupportedBy:(nonnull XMPPJID *)room{
    NSLog(@"serviceSupportedBy:-%@", room);
    [xmppMucSub subscribeTo:room nick:[xmppStream.myJID user] password:nil];
}
```

For more information refer below link.

https://github.com/Digithurst/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Extensions/MUC-Sub

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)